# Debug log for AccountContactRelation trigger doesn't show up on after delete

Tags: trigger, debugging, debug, debug-logs, accountcontactrelation

I have a trigger on AccountContactRelation object, which tracks `after update` and `after delete` events.

When I update ACR record - I see the log on the after update trigger transaction.

But when I delete a contact, which makes related ACR record be deleted as well, there is no debug log on the after delete event.

I've set flags on the current user, on the Automated Process user, on the trigger itself and the trigger handler - nothing.

Maybe someone can throw some light on this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

After further investigation of the trigger [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm) I've found this:

[image]

Just the case I had got into.